# How to integrate Cassandra with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, cluster-computing

I am trying to set up clustered Hadoop and Cassandra. Many sites I've read use a lot of words and concepts I am slowly grasping but I still need some help.

I have 3 nodes. I want to set up Hadoop and Cassandra on all 3. I am familiar with Hadoop and Cassandra individually but how so they work together and how do I configure them to work together? Also, how do I set up one node dedicated to, for example, analytics?

So far I have modified my `hadoop-env.sh` to point to Cassandra libs. I have put this on all of my nodes. Is that correct? What more do I need to do and how do I run it - start Hadoop cluster or Cassandra first?

Last little question: do I connect directly to Cassandra or to Hadoop from within my Java client?

Answer (score 1):

Rather then connecting them via your java client, you need to install Cassandra On top of Hadoop. Please follow [the article](http://gerrymcnicol.azurewebsites.net/index.php/2014/01/02/hadoop-and-cassandra-part-3-deploying-data-nodes-and-task-trackers-on-cassandra-nodes/) for step by step assistance.

BR

Comment: http://gerrymcnicol.azurewebsites.net/index.php/2014/01/02/hadoop-and-cassandra-part-3-deploying-data-nodes-and-task-trackers-on-cassandra-nodes/ link is not working